# get object from listview after clicking a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm trying to get the original object back from a listview, when I click on the button.

I thought it was in `e.Item.DataItem` but that always seems to be null.

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ListView ID="ListList" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCompanyName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbEmailAdress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddres") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAccountManagers" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Create or Update Account" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</form>


private void ListList_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the original datasource in session and get the real values while clicking a button.